# send the name of database in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in a SP:

```
   select @QUERY = 
      COALESCE(@QUERY+' UNION ALL ','') + 
     'SELECT ''' +
        c.name + ''' AS [ID], CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VarChar(MAX)) as [Value],''' + 
        t.name + ''' AS [Type] FROM ' + @dynDb + '.dbo.' +
        @TableName      + 
        ' WHERE actorId = '+ CAST(@ActorId  as nvarchar(max)) +
        ' and languageId = ''' + CAST(@LanguageId AS NVARCHAR(max))+ ''''    
   FROM cmssystemprocess.dbo.syscolumns c       
   INNER JOIN cmssystemprocess.dbo.SYSTYPES T ON T.XTYPE = C.XTYPE AND T.NAME != 'SYSNAME'      
   INNER JOIN cmssystemprocess.dbo.sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'         
   WHERE 
      o.name = @TableName and 
      (c.name like 'C%' or c.name like 'id') and 
      c.name not like 'created%'  
   ORDER BY c.colid
```

I want to get the name of database here in a variable (lets say @dyndb) and put it in the query instead of `cmssystemprocess.dbo.`.

Comment: Please explain "not working". What happens when you run this? Why is that wrong? "I tried all" - what else did you try? Please post your latest/closest attempt and explain its problem.

Comment: like this it is working but I mean i want to send instead of cmssystemprocess.dbo  a variable . I got the name of database in variable and i want to send it..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should really be using `sys.objects`. `sysobjects` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2000 (if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to parameterize the database you're querying is with dynamic SQL, which means your proc will have to create dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL. That can get ugly very quickly.

Some tips:

- use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and pass in all of your variables (@dynDb, @ActorId, etc), as well as @QUERY as an output variable, via the `@params` parameter.
- construct the dynamic SQL string using backticks (`) rather than doubling up on the single quotes.  Then, once the string is built, `` replace(@QUERY,'`','''') ``.
- when building dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL, use a different single characters in place of single quotes in each "level" of the SQL.

Using the SQL query in your question, I would

1. Change all instances of doubled-up single quotes to a single backtick, for readability.
2. Wrap the select statement with `` replace(...,'`','''') `` to restore the doubled-up quotes
3. Take the result of that and replace all single quotes with another seldom-used-but-reminiscent-of-a-quote character such as `^`
4. replace the instances of `cmssystemprocess` with a placeholder such as `#DB#`
5. Wrap the entire thing with two `replace()` functions to embed the DB name and change all the `^` back to doubled-up single quotes

Here's a mock-up:

```sql
-- Mimic stored proc parms
declare @QUERY      nvarchar(max)
       ,@SpDbParam  nvarchar(128) = 'cmssystemprocess'
       ,@dynDb      nvarchar(128)
       ,@ActorId    nvarchar(max)
       ,@LanguageId nvarchar(max)
       ,@TableName  nvarchar(128)
; -- end stored proc parms mockup


-- Actual code for your proc follows
declare @CMD nvarchar(max)
       ,@Params nvarchar(max) = '
 @dynDb      nvarchar(128)
,@ActorId    nvarchar(max)
,@LanguageId nvarchar(max)
,@TableName  nvarchar(128)
,@QUERY      nvarchar(max) output';

set @CMD = replace(replace('
 select @QUERY = replace(
      COALESCE(@QUERY+^ UNION ALL ^,^^) + 
     ^SELECT `^ +
        c.name + ^` AS [ID], CAST([^ + c.name + ^] AS VarChar(MAX)) as [Value],`^ + 
        t.name + ^` AS [Type] FROM ^ + @dynDb + ^.dbo.^ +
        @TableName      + 
        ^ WHERE actorId = ^+ CAST(@ActorId  as nvarchar(max)) +
        ^ and languageId = `^ + CAST(@LanguageId AS NVARCHAR(max))+ ^`^
       ,^`^,^^^^)
   FROM #DB#.dbo.syscolumns c
   INNER JOIN #DB#.dbo.SYSTYPES T ON T.XTYPE = C.XTYPE AND T.NAME != ^SYSNAME^
   INNER JOIN #DB#.dbo.sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = ^u^
   WHERE 
      o.name = @TableName and 
      (c.name like ^C%^ or c.name like ^id^) and 
      c.name not like ^created%^  
   ORDER BY c.colid'

,'#DB#',quotename(@SpDbParam))
,'^'   ,'''');

print @CMD; -- for debugging / showing output in this stackoverflow post

exec sp_executesql @CMD, @Params, @dynDb, @ActorId, @LanguageId, @TableName, @QUERY output;
```

```sql
 select @QUERY = replace(
      COALESCE(@QUERY+' UNION ALL ','') + 
     'SELECT `' +
        c.name + '` AS [ID], CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VarChar(MAX)) as [Value],`' + 
        t.name + '` AS [Type] FROM ' + @dynDb + '.dbo.' +
        @TableName      + 
        ' WHERE actorId = '+ CAST(@ActorId  as nvarchar(max)) +
        ' and languageId = `' + CAST(@LanguageId AS NVARCHAR(max))+ '`'
       ,'`','''')
   FROM [cmssystemprocess].dbo.syscolumns c
   INNER JOIN [cmssystemprocess].dbo.SYSTYPES T ON T.XTYPE = C.XTYPE AND T.NAME != 'SYSNAME'
   INNER JOIN [cmssystemprocess].dbo.sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
   WHERE 
      o.name = @TableName and 
      (c.name like 'C%' or c.name like 'id') and 
      c.name not like 'created%'  
   ORDER BY c.colid
```

Comment: FYI, this is **dangerously** open to injection. Rather than replacing the database name, inject it safely using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: To expand on Larnu's comment: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space  Note that `QuoteName` does not just toss square brackets around the input, it correctly handles square brackets that may occur within the object name.

Comment: I agree, which is why I replaced `#DB#` with `quotename(@SpDbParam)`.

I tried to disturb the rest of the query as little as possible.

The whole thing should have a bit of an overhaul:
- `CAST([' + c.name + ']` should be converted to use `quotename()`
- `FROM ' + @dynDb + '.dbo.'` as well